# Cocos2d black screen after app archive

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have cocos2d setup as a sub-project in my iOS app, running the latest release (3.5) and targeting iOS versions 9.0+. The problem I'm having is that the cocos2d screen is black when I download and install the app from TestFairy. I have debugged it both on the simulator and on real device and the cocos2d scene loads properly.

It's a simple finger painting app and it's all based on UIKit. Cocos2d is added to a ViewController in the standard way. The relevant code is:

```
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

// If the director's OpenGL view hasn't been set up yet, then we should create it now. If you would like to prevent this "lazy loading", you should initialize the director and set its view elsewhere in your code.
if ([director isViewLoaded] == NO) {
    director.view = [self createDirectorGLView];
    [self didInitializeDirector];
}
else {
    director.view.frame = [self getCanvasFrame];
    [director.view setNeedsLayout];
    [director.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

director.delegate = self;

// Add the director as a child view controller.
[self addChildViewController:director];

// Add the director's OpenGL view, and send it to the back of the view hierarchy so we can place UIKit elements on top of it.
[self.targetView addSubview:director.view];
[self.targetView sendSubviewToBack:director.view];

// Ensure we fulfill all of our view controller containment requirements.
[director didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

The `createDirectorGLView` is as follows:

```
- (CCGLView *)createDirectorGLView {
_glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[self getCanvasFrame]
                      pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                      depthFormat:0
               preserveBackbuffer:NO
                       sharegroup:nil
                    multiSampling:NO
                  numberOfSamples:0];

return _glView;
}
```

I also have a scene which contains the CCNode that handles the drawing. It is created like this:

```
@implementation IntroScene

- (id)init:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    _canvas = [[LineDrawer alloc] init];
    _canvas.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    _canvas.position = CGPointZero;
    _canvas.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:_canvas];
}

return self;
}

@end
```

I can't get access to the console logs for some reason while the app is running from TestFairy so I can't say what's going on there. When I debug from Xcode however, everything looks normal and the cocos2d canvas is loading/working just fine. I have a feeling it might be something to do with the way the project is archiving but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

**Edit**

So I managed to reproduce it in Debug mode on a device and I saw a few errors which I think are related to TestFairy's screen recording using OpenGL and cocos2d.

```
2016-06-06 12:49:56.362 GraffiTab[5654:2941813] *** Assertion failure in -[CCRenderStateGL initWithBlendMode:shader:shaderUniforms:copyUniforms:], /Users/georgichristov/Documents/Workspace/Examples/GraffiTab/GraffiTab-iOS/GraffiTab/ExternalLibs/Cocos2d/cocos2d/CCRendererBasicTypes.m:356
2016-06-06 12:49:56.362 GraffiTab[5654:2941813] [visit] error CCRenderState: Blending mode is nil
2016-06-06 12:49:56.705 GraffiTab[5654:2941813] TestFairy: Initializing SDK version 1.7.6 (20160531-772d18b7)
2016-06-06 12:49:58.057 GraffiTab[5654:2941813] TestFairy: Session started successfully
2016-06-06 12:49:58.929 GraffiTab[5654:2941813] Please remove uses of SCRCException!
```

Comment: Okay after some digging I found out that the root of the problem is the TestFairy SDK - looks like if I disable it, the canvas screen and cocos2d work just fine. I think it has something to do with recording the screen while the app is being used. I will continue investigating.